# Selenium webdriver screenshot not being taken from django

Tags: python, django, selenium

I have a functional test 'y1.py' which I have exported from the selenium IDE. It looks like:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
import unittest, time, re    

class Y1(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(30)
        self.base_url = "https://www.yahoo.com/"
        self.verificationErrors = []
        self.accept_next_alert = True

    def test_y1(self):
        driver = self.driver
        driver.get(self.base_url)
        driver.find_element_by_link_text("Weather").click()
        driver.save_screenshot('out11.png')    

    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.quit()
        self.assertEqual([], self.verificationErrors)    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

I have created a django app 'fts' and have placed the script in 'fts/tests.py. I added the line:

```
driver.save_screenshot('out11.png')
```

to the end to get a screenshot.

When I run the script from the command line using:

```
$ python manage.py test fts
```

the test passes but no screenshot is taken. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I personally use `get_screenshot_as_file` instead, this is my code :

```py
from selenium import webdriver

if __name__ == '__main__':

   browser = webdriver.Firefox()

   try:
      browser.get('http://www.google.com')
      browser.get_screenshot_as_file('screenshot.png')

   except Exception as e:
    print e
```

With `save_screenshot` you have to write the image to a file to keep in memory.

Comment: Thanks Vkt0r, your method does work but I realized that the screenshots are being saved to "PyCharm 3.0.1\jre\jre\bin" ??!!. for some reason specifying the path explicitly does not work ( driver.get_screenshot_as_file('c/foo1.png') ).

Comment: Very strange, I tested it using _Pycharm 2.7_ and works fine.